# Excel delete formula but keep values witha lot of rows

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I'm working with a macro excel. I'm trying to delete the formula but keep the values of the cells as it makes filtering/sorting so slow. I already tried the following:

```
Range("A2:E70000").Select
Selection.Copy 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False
```

and

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:E70000").Values = Sheet1.Range("A2:E70000").Values
```

but both of them take too long to finish(about 30mins. to complete). Are there any faster ways to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your actual code? That should be fast enough.

Comment: hi. this is the code im using right now Range("A2:E70000").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: And you're saying the second one is slow too? 30 mins? Btw, try what @PieterGeerkens suggested in his post. Also, all of those cells have formula or specific columns only? You might want to try reducing the cells to copy and paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bracket your code with

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

and you should see performance improve dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Visuals like selecting the cells are going to slow this down considerably. Also selecting to row 70,0000? If this is actually the case then fair enough, but if not then why?

Have edited your first code slightly. This will stop the screen updating until finished, won't 'select' any cells (visually) and will find the last actual row that is in use instead of just blanket selecting a range in hope it gets everything.

Try:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
with Sheet1.Range("A2:E" & Sheet1.Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
         SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False
end with
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```